# deselect radio button by click on it without clicking other radio button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am wondering how to deselect a Radio button by clicking on it (without clicking other radio button) as well as get rid of the function the radio button did in Tkinter (Python Gui 2.7).

I tried to make two rectangle of different color with two radio button.

(1). I need to deselect the radio button by clicking on it after selected (without clicking on     other).  And when I deselect the   associated rectangle should be removed.

(2). When I run the script one button (last one) showed selected though no function is running for that before clicking. How can I get rid of that ? I am not sure why it shows so and if I move my cursor on any radio button (not clicking) the button shows selected though no function is working before clicking.

I appreciate if somebody can help me in this regard.  I add my script here.

```
from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter
import tkColorChooser

def rec1 ():
    canvas_1= Canvas(r, height= 20, width = 50, bg = "blue").place(x = 150, y = 10)

def rec2 ():
    canvas_2= Canvas(r, height= 20, width = 50, bg = "red").place (x= 150, y = 40)

r = Tk()
r.geometry("300x100")

RB1 = Radiobutton (r, text = "Blue Rectangle", command = rec1, value = 1).place(x= 10, y = 10)
RB2 = Radiobutton (r, text = "Red Rectangle", command = rec2, value = 2).place(x= 10, y = 40)

r.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

A radio button represents an exclusive choice. If one of your valid choices is "no choice", then add another radiobutton to represent that.

You cannot (and should not) deselect a radio button by clicking on it. That's not how radio buttons are designed to work in any toolkit or in any language. If you want a single button to be able to be checked on or off, you should use a checkbutton instead of a radiobutton. Both of these widgets have very consistent and standard behaviors that you shouldn't change.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to remove the drawing (undo the function) by deselecting the Check button ?

Comment: @user2437648: you can associate a command with a checkbutton, and that command can do anything you want, including removing something from the canvas.